Run same command on multiple gitlab runners with different tags
Suppose I have 10 gitlab runners, each of them are configured for a gitlab group and specific tags, aka

runner1 accepts tag1 only
runner2 accepts tag2 only
...

Now I need to run commandA on all these runners, so I wrote this,
stages:
  - deploy

job1:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - tag1
    - tag2
    - tag3
    - ...
  script:
    - cmd1
    - cmd2

But gitlab does not run the job on any runners. If I leave only 1 tag in the tags it works fine.
What's wrong here?
